# Get item on mouseover from Grid

Tags: jquery, css

There are 16 items of the same  class. When mouseover effect takes place i want the specific item to change opacity and not all the items of the same class.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Vezz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

- http://jsfiddle.net/7Vezz/1/

i.e. something along these lines (`div`s as grid cells):

```
<div class="a">d1</div>
<div class="a">d2</div>
<div class="a">d3</div>
<div class="a">d4</div>
<div class="a">d5</div>
```

a bit of jQuery:

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('b');  
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass('b');  
})
```

and a touch of style:

```
.b { background-color: green; }
```

Comment: yes thats i great approach to the subject and works...cool :)

Comment: Actually, even better to use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) - see my edit. Anyway, glad that's what you needed!

Comment: hm the problem is ( in ur example and eventrually in my code ) that when i hover lets say d1 with class "a" i want the e1 from another class lets say "b2" to change... 
If its not clear enough what i say i can write the code on JSfiddle.

Like this :  http://jsfiddle.net/7Vezz/3/
When i hover on d1 item of the "a" class i want the background to apply on the e1 item of the "b" class.

Comment: This depends very much on how your page is structured, but try to use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Vezz/4/. This matches the class - i.e. the first element on the page with class `a` and the first element on the page with class `c` and so on.